# Unable to Copy Resources/data from SQLite Database stored in assets folder to /data/data/com.example.mohsinbhat.examsystem/databases/computer.db

Tags: android, sqlite

This is a Quiz app. There is Questions Activity on which there is a Progress Bar for timer, a TextView for questions and Four buttons for four options. The problem is that I am unable to read Questions and their answers from /data/data/com.example.mohsinbhat.examsystem/databases/computer.db.           Also /data/data/com.example.mohsinbhat.examsystem/databases/computer.db is empty .Null value is passed in the Question TextView and rest of the Button's text are empty.
[image: ScreenShot]

This  is my SQLite Helper Class named computer.java and another one for sports.java . Databases for these classes is stored in assets folder.

```
 //computer.java


 package com.example.mohsinbhat.examsystem.MyQuiz;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.database.SQLException;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
 import android.util.Log;

 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.OutputStream;
 import java.util.Locale;



   public class computer extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  private static final String Database_path =      
  "/data/data/com.example.mohsinbhat.examsystem/databases/";
  private static final String Database_name = "computer.db";
  //NAME of database stored in Assets folder
  private static final String Table_name = "computer";//name of table
  private static final String uid = "_id";//name of column1
  private static final String Question = "Question";//name of column2
  private static final String OptionA = "OptionA";//name of column3
  private static final String OptionB = "OptionB";//name of column4
  private static final String OptionC = "OptionC";//name of column5
  private static final String OptionD = "OptionD";//name of column6
  private static final String Answer = "Answer";//name of column7
  private static final int version = 1;


  public SQLiteDatabase sqlite;//object of type SQLiteDatabase
  private Context context;//Context object to get context from Question 
                        //Activity

  public computer(Context context) {//constructor
    super(context, Database_name, null, version);
    this.context = context;
   }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //No code because we have already created the database
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    //No code because we have already created the database
  }

  public void createDatabase() {
    createDB();
  }

   private void createDB() {

    boolean dbexist = DBexists();//calling the function to check db exists 
                                  //or not
    if (!dbexist)//if database doesnot exist
    {

        this.getReadableDatabase();//Create an empty file
        copyDBfromResource();//copy the database file information of assets 
                            //folder to newly create file
      }
    }

    private void copyDBfromResource() {

    InputStream is;
    OutputStream os;
    String filePath = Database_path + Database_name;
    try {
        is = context.getAssets().open(Database_name);//reading purpose
        os = new FileOutputStream(filePath);//writing purpose
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);//writing to file
        }
        os.flush();//flush the outputstream
        is.close();//close the inputstream
        os.close();//close the outputstream

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Error("Problem copying database file:");
      }
    }

   public void openDatabase() throws SQLException//called by onCreate method 
                                                  //of Questions Activity
   {

    String myPath = Database_path + Database_name;
    sqlite = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, 
   SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
   }

   private boolean DBexists()//Check whether the db file exists or not
  {
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    try {
        String databasePath = Database_path + Database_name;
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(databasePath, null, S 
     QLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        db.setVersion(1);
        db.setLockingEnabled(true);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e("Sqlite", "Database not found");
    }
    if (db != null)
        db.close();///close the opened file
    return db != null ? true : false;

    }

    public String readQuestion(int i)//Used to read the data from the Des.db 
                      //file where id is given and we choose id randomly
    {
    String Ans = "";//string that contains the required field  note that Ans 
                //is just a local string not related to Answer or Option...
    Cursor c = sqlite.rawQuery("SELECT " + Question + " FROM " + Table_name 
    + " WHERE "
             + uid + " = " + i + "", null);//cursor to that query

    if (c.moveToFirst())
        Ans = c.getString(0);
    else
        Ans = "";
    c.close();
   return Ans;
   }

    public String readOptionA(int i)//Used to read the data from the Des.db 
                      //file where id is given and we choose id randomly
  {
    String Ans = "";//string that contains the required field  note that Ans 
         //     is just a local string not related to Answer or Option...
    Cursor c = sqlite.rawQuery("SELECT " + OptionA + " FROM " + Table_name + 
        " WHERE "+ uid + " = " + i + "", null);//cursor to that query

    if (c.moveToFirst())
        Ans = c.getString(0);
    else
        Ans = "";
    c.close();
    return Ans;
   }

    public String readOptionB(int i)//Used to read the data from the Des.db 
        //file where id is given and we choose id randomly
  {
    String Ans = "";//string that contains the required field  note that Ans 
   is just a local string not related to Answer or Option...
    Cursor c = sqlite.rawQuery("SELECT " + OptionB + " FROM " + Table_name + 
 " WHERE " + uid + " = " + i + "", null);//cursor to that query

    if (c.moveToFirst())
        Ans = c.getString(0);
    else
        Ans = "";
    c.close();
    return Ans;
    }


  public String readOptionC(int i)//Used to read the data from the Des.db 
  file where id is given and we choose id randomly
  {
    String Ans = "";//string that contains the required field  note that Ans 
    is just a local string not related to Answer or Option...
    Cursor c = sqlite.rawQuery("SELECT " + OptionC + " FROM " + Table_name +        
    " WHERE " + uid + " = " + i + "", null);//cursor to that query

    if (c.moveToFirst())
        Ans = c.getString(0);
    else
        Ans = "";
    c.close();
    return Ans;
    }

       public String readOptionD(int i)//Used to read the data from the        
         //Des.db file where id is given and we choose id randomly
  {
      String Ans = "";//string that contains the required field  note that        
        Ans is just a local string not related to Answer or Option...
    Cursor c = sqlite.rawQuery("SELECT " + OptionD + " FROM " + Table_name +        
      " WHERE "+ uid + " = " + i + "", null);//cursor to that query

    if (c.moveToFirst())
        Ans = c.getString(0);
    else
        Ans = "";
    c.close();
    return Ans;
}

  public String readAnswer(int i)//Used to read the data from the Des.db 
                       //file where id is given and we choose id randomly
   {

    String Ans = "";//string that contains the required field
    Cursor c = sqlite.rawQuery("SELECT " + Answer + " FROM " + Table_name + 
            " WHERE "+ uid + " = " + i + "", null);//cursor to that query

    if (c.moveToFirst())
        Ans = c.getString(0);
    else
        Ans = "";
    c.close();
    return Ans;
    }
```

This is the xml layout of Questions Activity

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MyQuiz.Questions">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".Questions">

    <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
        android:id="@+id/donut_progress"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/donut_progress"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Questions"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#393737"
            android:textSize="28sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/OptionA"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/OptionB"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/OptionC"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/OptionD"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/play_button"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/donut_progress"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_option"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/plays"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="40sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: debug this : String filePath = Database_path + Database_name;

Comment: Do you get any stackerror?

Comment: You posted a lot of what i think is irrelevant code. Instead you should have explained how you wanted to use data from an sqlite database stored in assets folder. Which seems impossible to me. You should copy that database file first to a place where it can be used.

Comment: @solamente There is no stack error..

Comment: @greenapps computer.db is already copied  in "/data/data/com.example.mohsinbhat.examsystem/databases/computer.db"

Comment: Ok. But then that you copied it from assets is irrelevant. So why are you talking about assets then? Even talking " reading data from database in assets". And `The problem is that I am unable to read Questions and their answers from assets folder. `. You should use the copy in a normal manner.

Comment: @ greenapps I have not copied it ....it is autogenerated there. But the resources are not copied... I mean computer.db located in "/data/data/com.example.mohsinbhat.examsystem/databases/computer.db" is empty inside.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying your database from assets folders to device storage and then access it from there.
Below is sample code to copy it to local storage

```
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "yourdb.sqlite";
    private static final String DB_PATH_SUFFIX = "/databases/"; 

    //Use this function to openDatabase
    //This will copy the database if its not already copied or deleted
    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);

        if (!dbFile.exists()) {
            try {
                CopyDataBaseFromAsset();
                System.out.println("Copying sucess from Assets folder");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error creating source database", e);
            }
        }

        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS | SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
    }

    //This function copies the database to device storage
    public void CopyDataBaseFromAsset() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        String outFileName = getDatabasePath();

        File f = new File(context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + DB_PATH_SUFFIX);
        if (!f.exists())
            f.mkdir();

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    //Get absolute path of database
    private String getDatabasePath() {
        return context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + DB_PATH_SUFFIX
                + DATABASE_NAME;
    }
```